# Breaking formulas before and after binary operators

Tags: equations, line-breaking, typography

Page 195 of the TeXBook reads:

> Although formulas within a paragraph always break after binary operations and relations, displayed formulas always break before binary operations and relations.

What is the reason for this rule?

Comment: (Is this question acceptable here? It's not specifically about TeX, just about math typesetting.)

Answer (score 5):

That statement by Knuth regarding displayed equations is Knuth's opinion. It is not a universally accepted typography rule. From a quick glance at multiple books and journals, there apparently is not a universally accepted typography rule.

- Some use the rule as espoused by Knuth.
- Some use the opposite rule: displayed equations are split after a binary operator.
- You would think that those are the only choices. They aren't. Some take a third route: Repeat the binary operator at the end of one line and at the start of the next.

Comment: Is there any reason for this rule, though? Just how Knuth felt on the day that he was writing the book?

Comment: @Ben: You'll have to ask Knuth. I can see compelling arguments for all three methods.

Comment: The rule espoused by Knuth isn't his. He was repeating conventional wisdom. This appears to be the most commonly used of the three, but all three are in use, particularly the first (break before a binary operator) and the last (repeat the broken operator).

Comment: @Ben Alpert: Probably there is no real reason. Many arbitrary choices are made in TeX/LaTeX. The 3rd choice (as written by David Hammen - Repeat the binary operator at the end of one line and at the start of the next.) is default in Cyrillic typography (Russian for example). Also see this document, and especially page 15 [ISO 31 conforming typesetting in LATEX](http://moritz-nadler.de/formelsatzVortrag.pdf).

Comment: Some typographical rules are, in fact, a mere convention. However, some of those conventions have been collected in books that serve as guidelines. In the updated edition of 1999 of the classic *Mathematics into Type* by Ellen Swanson, the rule is mentioned in Section 3.3.4 *Rules for breaking equations in display*: "In display, equations may be broken before an operator but *not* after an operator". (I don't own the 1971 first edition, but surely this same rule was there?).

Comment: Also, The Chicago Manual of Style says "If necessary, displayed
expressions may be broken before a relation or operation sign.", and refers to *Mathematics into Type* for more information.

Comment: When I write code, I break long mathematical expressions after a binary operator. That dangling operator at the end of the line gives a clue to the reader (or maintainer) that there is more to the expression at hand. When I document that code, I break before the binary operator. Think of `sum = (long expression) - (second long expression) + (third long expression) - (final long expression)`. Because of how subtraction works, pairing the operator with the subtrahend/addend as opposed to hiding the operator at the end of the previous line improves comprehensibility (at least for the sighted).

Comment: @DavidHammen Your rule does not work for the last line - there is no clue for the reader that this line is a continuation (think of your example but without the parentheses). Breaking before the operator, in languages with `;` required on the other hand, gives a clear indication on *each line* that it is not standalone. Also the third rule from your answer can be really confusing in case of subtraction (`a -\n- b` can be both interpreted as `a - (-b)` and `a - b`).

Comment: @BartoszKP All three options have their upsides and downsides. I intentionally merely reported what I have seen in print. I intentionally did not report my preference in the answer. The reason for the six year delay in my response to you is that I just received a downvote on this answer, and since there was no comment, I haven't the foggiest idea why the downvote occurred. But I did see that I did not respond to you.

Comment: @DavidHammen :-) My response was not addressed at your post, but at your comment from Jun 19, 2011 at 23:05 just above, about how you write code. Unfortunately I don't know the reason why I replied to you after 7 years. I'm looking forward to your response some time within the next decade.

Comment: @BartoszKP Haha :-) Good one. I had switched my style shoirtly after I wrote that comment because a reader of my code was confused by putting an operator (in particular, a minus sign) at the end of the previous line. I rewrote that code so that the binary operator was at the start of the next line.  I asked others which they thought was clearer, and most of them liked the operator at the start of the line format. I don't program anymore as my flatulence is well-aged (in other words, I am a retired old fart).

Comment: @DavidHammen Thank you for sharing your experience! Also, thanks for an extremely prompt response, and accept my almost-equally-quick reply in return ;)

Answer (score 1):

Scenario where "Formulas within a paragraph always break after binary operations" makes sense:

```
f(x) = very + long + inline + equation + 

----------------------------------------- Page break

that + spans + multiple + pages.
```

The benefit of breaking after the operator is that it's clearer that the equation will continue on the next page.

---

In contrast, for "displayed formulas always break before binary operations", displayed equations don't usually contain page breaks in between, so that advantage is mitigated. This feels more of a stylistic choice than the previous. One possibility is that having an operator on the left makes it more "obvious" that a formula continues across lines *before* you begin to read the formula.

```
f(x) = usually + we + read + left-to-right, + so + having + the + operator
       + on + the + left + indicates + to + us + that + the + equation
       + will + later + break

       ^
       |
       ----- an operator on the left is much more prominent
             and predictable (it's always in the same spot!)
```

That is, a reader's eyes may naturally scan in the following order:

```
read_first  =  read_third
     read_second    read_fourth
```

If an operator occupies the "read_second" spot, that is advantageous since the reader's eyes can "flow" 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 and pick up that the equation is bigger than one line.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but a very widely used rule is to **never** allow an equation to span multiple pages. LaTeX and amsmath support this rule in several of their mathematics environments.